# How can I make the Year/Date tag be displayed completely in media players?

Tags: vlc-media-player, mp3, date, tags, id3

I'm using Mp3Tag to tag some of my music files, and I like to use the YYYY.MM.dd format. I prefer that instead of just the year.

However, I found that both in VLC Media Player and in Groove Music, only the YYYY field is displayed.

Demonstration:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt6oa.png)

What can be done so the whole date is displayed?

Comment: Have you tried resizing the columns?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, that's not the issue. http://prntscr.com/o9ybam

Comment: There is a VLC open ticket for this [#3442 (Allow full date metadata in Media Information panel) – VLC](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/3442)

Comment: @DavidPostill The ticket has been open for a decade now, it's likely never being addressed. I'm commenting again because of new relevant info: https://i.imgur.com/x91EyxC.png As shown, FLAC's date is fully displayed, MP3's isn't. Additionally, I tried using MP3tag's extended tag "ReleaseTime", which does not show up in Windows properties nor on VLC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a while to put the answer here but, basically, it has to do with the different tagging systems for the different audio files - *mp3* and *flac*, one uses **ID3** and the other **[Vorbis Comments](https://xiph.org/flac/faq.html#general__tagging)**.

For *flac*, it seems you can input pretty much whatever and it'll be fine - even letters - and they'll show up in most programs [(at least on all I've tried)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOIGc.png).

Since you can input full-date values like **`YYYY.MM.DD`** in *mp3* files with mp3tag, it's not like **ID3** doesn't support them to some degree, but they won't show up in most programs, and the ones that do display it, don't do so past **`YYYY`**.

I don't actually know the workings behind the problem, but this is a lead, at the very least. I won't investigate further as it is beyond my capabilities.

Comment: An _informal convention_ exists where the `TYER` frame can store dates as `YYYY-MM-DD`, despite the fact it was originally defined as 4 bytes only. foobar2000 and XMPlay can display it and sort by date correctly. The id3v2.4 spec suggests `TDRC` and `TDRL` for this format, but their intended purposes are rather specific (recording / release date), hence TYER's use as a single catch-all. VLC will likely never fix this as they only provide the bare minimum for field sorting in their playlist.